Validating a certificate from the key vault in my connection string, EF Core + Azure function
I need to verify a certificate in my connection string (EF Core) in my Azure function.
I have this connection string :
Server=**.database.azure.com;Database=dbheat;Uid=****;Pwd=****;SslMode=VerifyCA;SslCert='/'",

The certificate needs to be read from Azure Keyvault with the certificate in it. Any idea how to get a certificate from KV and add it into my connection string.
If I add the certificate into my solution manually then I get this error:

The collection already contains item with the same key 'net.transport'

Which now kind of makes sense because of getting a path in an azure function is causing me trouble and I don't want to hardcode my certificate into my function.

I have cracked this problem by creating an connection string that allows parameters.
var connectionstring = new MySqlConnector.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{   
    Server = "whatever.mysql.database.azure.com",
    Database = "db",
    UserID = "un",
    Password = "password",
    SslMode= MySqlConnector.MySqlSslMode.VerifyCA,
    SslCert = cert.ToString()

}.ToString();

then i created a variable that stores my pem details - the stuff after BEGIN CERTIFICATE in the PEM and then used
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certpem));

to get the string as a certificate in .net
Viola - it works
